# Search text file for variable, take data and assign a variable to it (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have very large set of data stored as a plain text file. Example as follows:

```
uss/inde_ind,13294
uss/isk,1
uss/jpy,126
uss/jpy lrg,0
uss/kes,4
uss/kwd,423
uss/ktz tom,126
```

I'm trying to build some code that will allow people to search for some specific terms and copy the related numeric value into a variable.
So for example, I want people to be able to look for 'uss/inde_ind' and for it to return the value: 13294

Do you have any advice on how to achieve this?

I believe I would have to use re, in some form or other, but I am quite unfamiliar with this particular library, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thus far, I've created the search terms I want to look for:

```
v1 = "uss/inde_ind"
v2 = "uss/kes"
```

With the help of Matiiss, code now looks like this:

```
def get_values(filename: str, search_terms: list) -> dict:
    """Searches the given file for the given search terms and returns found values."""
    dct = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            term, value = line.strip().split(',')
            if term in search_terms:
                dct[term] = float(value)
    # if any of the search terms were not found then update the dictionary 
    # with the remaining ones and set their value to None
    if len(dct.keys()) != len(search_terms):
        dct.update({k: None for k in search_terms if k not in dct})
    return dct


search_for = [
    v1, 
    v2
]

result = get_values(copy, search_for)
print(result)
```

However when I run this block, I get:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like you need `re` to do this, you just want exact matches?

Comment: I'm looking for the number after the search term, I want to be able to store the number specifically so that I can enter it into a dataframe later.

Comment: Why not read the data into a dataframe using `read_csv` from `pandas`? It would then be easy to get the data you want.

Comment: It isn't coming from a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't have done it without the help of Matiiss, but by using tuple unpacking, I got the issue fixed:

```
def get_values(filename: str, search_terms: list) -> dict:
    """Searches the given file for the given search terms and returns found values."""
    dct = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            term, *value = line.strip().split(',')
            if term in search_terms:
                dct[term] = float(*value)
    # if any of the search terms were not found then update the dictionary 
    # with the remaining ones and set their value to None
    if len(dct.keys()) != len(search_terms):
        dct.update({k: None for k in search_terms if k not in dct})
    return dct


search_for = [
    v1, 
    v2
]

result = get_values('myfile.txt', search_for)
print(result)
```

Comment: btw, I just noticed but you shouldn't do `float(*value)`, currently `value` will be a list, but it will contain only one item so unpacking all the values will give only one value to the `float`, but if there is anything more separated by the comma, you will get an error. but if you expect there to perhaps be more values in the `.split` returned list, you can for example (I included it in my answer too) do `term, value, *_ = line.strip().split(',')` so that any other values if there are any would be dismissed, only the first two values will be used

Comment: Thanks for continuing to look at this. However if I change that line to your recommendation I get: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 1)

Comment: yes, that is what I thought about too and I came to the conclusion that it would be better then to use in your example `dct[term] = float(value[0])`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

```py
def get_values(filename: str, search_terms: list) -> dict:
    """Searches the given file for the given search terms and returns found values."""
    dct = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            term, value = line.strip().split(',')
            if term in search_terms:
                dct[term] = float(value)
    # if any of the search terms were not found then update the dictionary 
    # with the remaining ones and set their value to None
    if len(dct.keys()) != len(search_terms):
        dct.update({k: None for k in search_terms if k not in dct})
    return dct


search_for = [
    'uss/inde_ind',
    'uss/kes',
    'not/real'
]

result = get_values('myfile.txt', search_for)
print(result)
```

Simply read the file line by line, check if the value before comma is in the search terms and if it is add it to the dictionary with a float value after the comma. If some terms were not found add them to the dictionary with value of None.

Also added a test case for a term that is not in the file to show what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help this far. I've got an issue which I'm not sure about. I've amended your search_for list somewhat to include the v1 and v2 variables. But I'm getting the following error when I run the block: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper" any idea why this might be?

Comment: @alec22 so I will guess that you did something like this: `get_values(v1, v2) (or `get_values(search_for, 'filename.txt')`)`? anyhow, the first argument should be the filename, but hard to tell what you did wrong since you haven't shown how you called the function

Comment: So the only difference between your code and mine thus far is I did get_values(v1, v2) and then on the end I did: result = get_values(copy, search_for)
print(result). Copy being the variable name of the txt file.

Comment: still not understanding but if you want the `v1` and `v2` to be included the easiest is to just add them to the list: `search_for = ['some string', v1, v2]` (you could provide the current state of the code in your question (which you can edit btw))

Comment: @alec22 what exactly is `copy`? it should be a string or path like object or bytes as the error suggests

Comment: 'copy' is the variable that I've assigned the txt containing the data to. So it contains the "uss/inde_ind,13294
uss/isk,1
uss/jpy,126
uss/jpy lrg,0
uss/kes,4
uss/kwd,423
uss/ktz tom,126" stuff

Comment: @alec22 yes, but what is `copy` in the code? how do you define `copy`?

Comment: Copy i simply created by this: copy = open("copy.txt", "w")

Comment: @alec22 yes, but as you can see, then the function as an argument takes in the file NAME not a file object, so really it should be `copy = 'copy.txt'` and then `result = get_values(copy, search_for)`

Comment: @alec22 actually you may be interested in the [`csv` library (built-in)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)